# fold: invalid number of columns when running script with arguments

Tags: bash, arguments, fold, command-substitution

I got a strange behavior when running a script with arguments that contains a command substitution. I would like to understand why is this behavior happening. The script is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# MAIL=$1
# USER=$2
PASSWORD=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w ${1:-20} | head -n 1);
echo "$PASSWORD"
```

Then I run: `./test.sh mail user`, I get the error:
`fold: invalid number of columns: ‘mail’`
and the Password is not generated.

If I don't pass an argument or I don't generate the password, it works fine.

## Update (for understanding the behavior)

I think I've found out what is happening:
When running a script with two arguments the `$1 and $2` have the passed values. Example:
`./test.sh arg1 arg2` have `$1 -> arg1` and `$2 -> arg2`

When using a pipe inside a script, the original arguments are still passed and thus if you have two arguments as input you will have the piped output inserted into the third place `$3`.

- `$1 -> arg1`
- `$2 -> arg2`
- `$3 -> piped output`
  So a working solution would be:

```sh
PASSWORD=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w ${3:-20} | head -n 1);
```

but if you vary the input arguments, it will not work. Therefore the best solution is what @KamilCuk suggested:

```sh
PASSWORD=$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 20 | head -n 1);
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you expect `fold -w mail` to do? 
Do you understand what `${1:-20}` does?

Comment: I pipe "cat /dev/urandom and filter it to valid characters (tr -dc ...). fold should take the first 20 valid characters but not any argument I pass to the script (like "mail")

1. I'm not expecting at all to have "fold -w mail".
2. ${1:-20} takes the first 20 characters from the generated string

Comment: `${1:-20} takes the first 20 characters from the generated string` No. `fold` when passed a number of `20` takes the first 20 characters. When` $1` is `mail`, then it does `fold -w mail`, which is invaild. When `$1` is unset or empty, then `fold` is passed `20`. `I'm not expecting at all to have "fold -w mail"` Then do you understand what `${var:-something}` means? Add `set -x` to debug your scripts.

Comment: Thank you, now I am a step further. With `${1:-something}` I am expecting the first argument that the pipe passes to it. It works if you just run `./test.sh` but it seems that the `$1` is replaced when I add an argument to the script like `./test.sh arg` right?

Comment: [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). [bash positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not wish to pass the first script argument to `fold`, then do not use `$1` in it.

```
PASSWORD=$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 20 | head -n 1);
#                                                      ^^ - pass the number, not $1
echo "$PASSWORD"
```